# Error: Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module 'ComponentsModule', почему?

Tags: angular2

Добрый вечер. Нужна помощь. Уже второй час бьюсь над решением (гугл не помог).
Выводится вышеуказанная ошибка.
Кратко о коде:
[image]

По наименованию ошибки могу предполагать, что `Модуль ComponentsModule` декларирует компонент `InputComponent` как `undefined`.
Код из файла `InputComponent`:

```
<code lang="javascript">
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { InputInnerComponent } from "./input-inner";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "input-comp",
    templateUrl: "input.component.html",
})
export class InputComponent {}
</code>
```

Если понадобятся ещё какие либо файлы, прошу отписаться.
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то Вам нужно в `components.module.ts` в `NgModule` добавить `exports: [InputComponent]`. После этого `AppModule` будет иметь к нему доступ.

Comment: Сам спросил, сам ответил. Ответ, здесь: https://toster.ru/q/410498

Comment: @УмидМусаев ссылка на другом сайте может быть недоступна со временем. Решение по Вашему вопросу возможно поможет кому-нибудь в дальнейшем. Если Ваше решение отличается, пожалуйста, опубликуйте Ваш ответ или удалите Ваш вопрос вовсе.